# Lose Focus and Update Source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus

I've got a MainView and a ChildView and a MainViewModel and a ChildViewModel.

On my MainView i got a SaveButton which is bound to the VM through a command.

When that button is clicked the textbox on the ChildView should lose the focus and update their VM.

How can i do that?

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="FOR [percent]" Width="*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Knowles_ShiftreportEditor_Controls:NumberTextbox  Text="{Binding ForValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" AllowsDecimal="True"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have the same problem with button IsDefault=true or Keybinding. what i have done is to register an eventhandler in my app.xaml.cs OnStartup()

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
            typeof(Button), 
            ButtonBase.ClickEvent, 
            new RoutedEventHandler(
                (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        if (sender != null && sender is Button)
                        {
                            (sender as Button).Focus();
                        }
                    }));

     }
```

now the focus is set to the button and the textbox binding work like expected.

Comment: does you textbox binding work when you step out of your textbox with tab? maybe you post some code which shows the behavior

Comment: If i step out of the Textbox with Tab it works. Also the Eventhandler and the Focus Method is Called